# What version of IE is used in the WPF .NET 3.5sp1 frame control?

Tags: .net, wpf

When using the frame control to display web content?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

Same version as one installed on that system. It just reuses already existing IE dlls.

Answer (score 1):

But it might render is some other compatibility mode!
So, if you're expecting rendition of some HTML5 code, it might not be visible because by default it runs in IE7 compatibility mode.